# Parsing data from excel sheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any gem or plugins in ruby on rails which will read the data from excel sheet.

Answer (score 4):

Try Spreadsheet GEM. It provides facility to read xls file. You can also try [Roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/).